# How to put an auto generated html template inside an iframe which is inside a dialog box

Tags: jquery, html

I have an auto generated html template:

```
var html = engagement_tech_file_upload.file_upload({ file_types : file_types, selected_file_type: selected_file_type });
```

And with a click of a button, a dialog box will appear:

```
$('#multiple-file').live('click', function () {
$(".tech-file-upload-dialog").html('<iframe>'+html+'</iframe>').dialog('open');
});
```

Which will include the html template inside the iframe. But this doesnt work, how to do this properly?

Comment: can you give fiddle demo

Answer (score 0):

Can't make out much from your code-snippet, but if I am not wrong you want to write some `html` into an `iframe`.

Assuming that *multiple-file* is the button, you can do it like this:

```
$('#multiple-file').live('click', function () {
    var html = "<html><body><h2>New Document</h2></body></html>";
    var iframeDoc = $('#iframeId')[0].contentWindow.document;
    $("body", iframeDoc).append(html);
});
```

Where *html* is your template and *iframeId* is the *Id* of your iframe. Put your `iframe` inside a `div` inside the `dialog`.

Here is a sample fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Y5xPY/1/